# Chrome.serial API - reading the right number of bytes via serial

Tags: javascript, serial-port, arduino, google-chrome-app

I'm working on a Google Chrome extension that communicates with an Arduino UNO over serial. I wrote the following function `sendSerialCmd` that takes a port (string), a serial_cmd (ArrayBuffer), and a callback function that gets passed readInfo.data (an ArrayBuffer) that is read in from the serial connection.

```
var CONNECTION_ID = -1;
var sendSerialCmd = function(port, serial_cmd, callback) {
chrome.serial.open(port, null, function(openInfo){
    CONNECTION_ID = openInfo.connectionId;
    if (CONNECTION_ID == -1) {
        console.log('Could not connect to serial');
        return;
    }
    chrome.serial.write(CONNECTION_ID, serial_cmd, function(writeInfo){
        chrome.serial.read(CONNECTION_ID, 8, function(readInfo){
            callback(readInfo.data);
        });
    })
});
chrome.serial.close(CONNECTION_ID, function(result){ console.log(result) });
};
```

One of the problems I've run into is the third parameter passed to the `chrome.serial.read()` function. In the [chrome.serial](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/serial.html#method-read) API, the third parameter is the **bytesToRead ( integer ): The number of bytes to read**, however, the number of bytes coming in from my Arduino are subject to change. Sometimes I may get 8 bytes, other times more. What's the best way of getting all the bytes sent back from my Arduino?

Arduino has a novel solution through a function called [Serial.available()](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Available) which returns the number of bytes available to read. Is there something similar I can do with the Chrome.serial API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no similar functionality to `Serial.available()` in the Chrome serial API, but you should just poll for some reasonable number of bytes and process the data at your own pace.

If a `read` is requested for (say) 1024 bytes and only 8 bytes are available, the `read`  should still succeed quickly with just 8 bytes. If there is an 8-byte message and a 12-byte message available, the `read` will succeed with 20 bytes and you can apply whatever logic is necessary to parse the resulting data.

FYI, the serial API is changing soon in Canary and you will no longer be responsible for manually polling with `read`. Instead Chrome will poll for you and fire `chrome.serial.onReceive` events as data is available from an open device.

Comment: I ended up creating a recursive function that continually reads for 1 byte at a time with a terminating condition of readInfo.bytesRead = -1, which seemed to get the job done. When can I expect the Chrome team to push out chrome.serial.onReceive? Thanks!

Comment: I can't find any references to the `onReceive` event you mention, could you please post the source of that information? Thanks.

Comment: When I made the original post, you'll note that I said "soon" :)  You can find a reference for the new API  at http://developer.chrome.com/apps/serial.html.

Comment: Annoyingly this "new" API while documented is not a part of the public release of chrome yet.  as of Jan 12 2014 :(

Comment: It's coming in Chrome 33, which will be beta soon. It is unfortunate that the API changed so much after going stable already, but it seemed like the right thing to do in this case. [Here](http://pastebin.com/St3VchWz) is some polyfill that will let you use most of the new API on Chrome versions prior to 33 so you can begin porting code. Some new features like custom bitrates and timeouts are unsupported even with the polyfill, but that shouldn't be surprising.